# Obtain website's description (meta) from ODP DMOZ.org using PHP

Tags: php, curl, dmoz

I am working on a php website. What I want to do is to retireve description or meta information of websites. What I hope to do is to obtain the information from dmoz.org, is there a way of doing such a thing ?

If not, then what are other alternatives ? cURL ?

Many thanks,

EDIT:

Apparently my question wasn't clear. dmoz.org is open directory that gives you information about websites. The information given is different than the meta tags from the website itself. So what i want to do is getting such information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built-in function for extracting the meta information:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://dmoz.org');
print_r($tags);
```

Comment: Sorry, apparently my question wasn't clear :( dmoz.org is open directory that gives you information about websites. The information given is different than the meta tags from the website. So what i want to do is getting such information ...

Comment: So are you wanting to pull information from the results of a query against a domain name, like this:http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=stackoverflow.com

Comment: Many thanks :)... Exactly what i need. Would you kindly lead me or guide how can read what's in the page ? for example parsing the tags ?

Comment: This is probably the best PHP html parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. I'd start there. It breaks the entire document down into elements you that you can search.